# "Header content contains invalid characters" error when piping multipart upload part into a new request

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, requestjs, multiparty

My express server receives file uploads from browsers.  The uploads are transferred as `multipart/form-data` requests; I use multiparty to parse the incoming entity body.

Multiparty allows you to get a *part* (roughly, a single form field like an `<input type="file">`) as a readable stream.  I do not want to process or store the uploaded file(s) on my web server, so I just pipe the uploaded file part into a request made to another service (using the request module).

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.on('part', function(part) {

        var serviceRequest = request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://other-service/process-file',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
            }
        }, function(err, svcres, body) {
            // handle response
        });

        part.pipe(serviceRequest);
    });

    form.parse(req);
});
```

This works correctly most of the time.  node automatically applies chunked transfer encoding, and as the browser uploads file bytes, they are correctly sent to the backend service as a raw entity body (without the multipart formatting), which ultimately gets the complete file and returns successfully.

However, ***sometimes*** the request fails and my callback gets called with this `err`:

```
TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters 
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:360:11) 
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:85:14) 
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10) 
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:199:15) 
    at Request.start (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:744:32) 
    at Request.write (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1421:10) 
    at PassThrough.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20) 
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13) 
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:188:7) 
    at PassThrough.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:381:10) 
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:761:34) 
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:743:3) 
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11) 
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

I'm unable to explain where that error is coming from since I only set the `Content-Type` header and the stack does not contain any of my code.

Why do my uploads occasionally fail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That `TypeError` [gets thrown by node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.8.4/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L363) when making an outgoing HTTP request if there is any string in the request `headers` option object contains a character [outside the basic ASCII range](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.8.4/lib/_http_common.js#L278-L292).

In this case, it appears that the `Content-Disposition` header is getting set on the request even though it is never specified in the request options.  Since that header contains the uploaded filename, this can result in the request failing if the filename contains non-ASCII characters.  ie:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: public-server
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--ex
Content-Length: [bytes]

----ex
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="totally legit .pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

[body bytes...]
----ex--
```

The request to `other-service/process-file` then fails because multiparty stores the part headers on the `part` object, which is also a readable stream representing the part body.  When you `pipe()` the `part` into `serviceRequest`, the request module [looks to see if the piped stream has a `headers` property, and if it does, copies them to the outgoing request headers](https://github.com/request/request/blob/v2.81.1/request.js#L505-L511).

This results in the outgoing request that would look like:

```
POST /process-file HTTP/1.1
Host: other-service
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="totally legit .pdf"
Content-Length: [bytes]

[body bytes...]
```

...except that node sees the non-ASCII character in the `Content-Disposition` header and throws.  The thrown error is caught by request and passed to the request callback function as `err`.

This behavior can be avoided by removing the part headers before piping it into the request.

```
delete part.headers;
part.pipe(serviceRequest);
```

Answer (score 19):

This example shows how to send file as an attachment with national symbols in the filename.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const contentDisposition = require('content-disposition');
...

// req, res - http request and response
let filename='totally legit .pdf';
let filepath = 'D:/temp/' + filename;               

res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Disposition': contentDisposition(filename), // Mask non-ANSI chars
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
});

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
readStream.pipe(res);
readStream.on('error', (err) => ...);
```

Comment: link to [content-disposition](https://github.com/jshttp/content-disposition) lib

Comment: alternate way : to use encodeURI. 'Content-Disposition': encodeURI(filename),

Answer (score 1):

As like as @arrow cmt before, using encodeURI(filename) on your Content-disposition header. In client, you using decodeURI method to decode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **encodeURI** server side and **decodeURI** client side.

**Example with a csv file, using an Express server and a JavaScript client.**

*server*

```
router.get('urlToGetYourFile', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const filename = await functionToGetYourFilename();
    const file = await functionToGetYourFile();
    res
      .status(200)
      .header({
        'content-Type': 'text/csv'
        'content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + encodeURI(filename)
      })
      .send(file.toString('binary'));
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ error });
  }
}
```

*client*

```
const getFile = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('urlToGetYourFile');
    const filename = decodeURI(response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1]);
    const type = { type: 'text/csv' };
    const blob = new Blob([response.data], type);
    return new File([blob], filename, type);
  } catch(error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```